# How to always display an HTML file and embed new pages inside of it?

Tags: html, css, firefox

So I created an HTML GUI for a touchscreen monitor. The browser is supposed to always stay in fullscreen. Now I want to embed another website inside my HTML, which works pretty well.

My only problem now is, that when I click through the embedded webpage, new pages open without my GUI. This is a problem because I added navigation functionality to the GUI and since it always runs in fullscreen I can't use the back and forward buttons either.

So is there a way to make Firefox always open my HTML GUI, when it opens a new page and open the requested page as embedded in my GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide more information about how did you embed other site in your html gui.

The solution is to use `<iframe>` element, then all the links inside the iframe should be open in that iframe. And if you want any other link from your GUI to be open in that iframe, just add   `target="name_of_the_iframe"`  to that  element, and a attribute `name="name_of_the_iframe`" to the iframe (ofcourse "name_of_the_iframe" is an example).

Comment: Well, this is more or less what I want. Is there a way to force iframe to open any new link inside the frame, as well??

Comment: Yes (that's what I wrote). For example link in your GUI can look like this: <a href="google.com" target="your_iframe_name">link</a>  and your iframe should look like this: <iframe name="your_iframe_name" src="initial_url"></iframe>

Comment: Yes, I tried it with a different site now. It works for e.g. Wikipedia, but not for the site I intend to use it for. The link looks something like this "https://abc.def.ghi.website.com:50001/JKLM/NO/Homepage_PQ001/Homepage.htm". Any idea why this could be?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using an iframe

From w3schools: "An iframe is used to display a web page within a web page."

Take a look at this link: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp